# How to routes in Django with Vue?

Tags: django, vue.js, routes, vue-router, django-urls

I want to create MPA with Vue for the frontend and Django for the backend. I only find a way to render the different routes via the Vue part. I made this with the **vue create** command.  For example:

App.vue

> ```
>   <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
>   <router-link to="/about">About</router-link> |
>   <router-link to="/profile">Profile</router-link>
> ```

This is just because I can't find the way to render my Vue pages from urls.py in my django application. For example, that's not my routes because I can't find how to write them:

> ```
> path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
> ```

Can I render Vue pages in urls.py and how?

Comment: If you're talking about SSR, you should check out Nuxt. If you're not referring to that, your Vue routes are completely separate from your Django routes.

Comment: @Mike can I make MPA from SSR with Nuxtjs? And what do you mean by Vue routes are completety separate from Django routes? Is this mean that it will works if I define my Vue pages in both routes vue and django?

Comment: Yes. MPA is possible with Nuxt! And sorry I did not explain much. Vue's router is client-side meaning no additional resource requests happen when navigating through a page with VueRouter. Django's router is server-side, meaning a request has to be made from a client to procure a resource, then it is sent to the client for rendering. There's a whole topic to talk about these two things with the main difference being one is client-side logic and the other is server-side.

Comment: @Mike ah okay and really appreciate your explanation because I was really confused about combining these two, because most of the resources are just for SPA projects. Now will check Nuxt.js and how to implement my pages thank you)))

Comment: You're welcome. And technically, you don't have to use SSR to use Vue with Django. You can use Django as you normally would. 

In your Django views, you can add in your Vue logic to that specific page. So say your `/about` route will have a different JS file with different Vue logic compared to your `/contact` route.